# do-releas-upgrade non working (Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10) Operation not permitted or denied

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, update-manager, do-release-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 without avail.

`do-release-upgrade` works up until the fetch of new packages. Then the terminal output gives:

```
Fetching
E: setgroups 65534 failed - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
E: setegid 65534 failed - setegid (1: Operation not permitted)
E: seteuid 104 failed - seteuid (1: Operation not permitted)
E: setgroups 0 failed - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
```

This output is the same for `update-manager -d` does not work (stucks at download for package 3, but same error output as do-release-upgrade)

I've search for a while without any avail. I do not have docker installed.

`update-manager -d` does not work (stucks at download for package 3, but same error output as do-release-upgrade)

In contrast to update-manager, the output of do-release-upgrade is:

```
Err http://ubuntu.mirror.su.se/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 libc6 amd64 2.30-0ubuntu2                                                                                                                                   
  Could not open file /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/libc6_2.30-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 193.11.30.223 80]
```

For every package that should be upgraded.

I have absolutaley no idea whats wrong..
I've tried to remove all packages in /var/cache/apt/archives/partial
I've tried to change deb servers.

`apt update` and reinstall of disco packages still work.
`apt clean` has no affect.

If of interest, I am unable to login to the desktop using GDM and instead I have to `startx` from tty2.

Answer (score 1):

Found this command which solved my issue:

```
sudo pkexec do-release-upgrade -m desktop
```

Comment: I've had the same problem for *years*, do-release-upgrade has never worked for me, and always left my system broken. This worked ☺ Any idea why? I can only imagine some bug in our sudo config, or do-release-upgrade is broken.